# Push array of objects that make up a count of 100

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects like the following:

```
const items = [
    {
        'name': 'P1',
        'value': 50
    },
    {
        'name': 'P1',
        'value': 49
    },
    {
        'name': 'P2',
        'value': 50
    },
    {
        'name': 'P3',
        'value': 50
    }
]
```

I need to add up the values and then push into an array of objects only if the 1 or more objects make up a `value` total of 100.

Expected output:

```
const groupedItems = [
  [
    {
        'name': 'P1',
        'value': 50
    },
    {
        'name': 'P1',
        'value': 49
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      'name': 'P2',
      'value': 50
    },
    {
        'name': 'P3',
        'value': 50
    }
  ]
]
```

What I have tried:

```
const temp = [];

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  if ((items[i] + items[i + 1]) < 100) {
    temp.push(items[i]);
  }
}

groupedItems.push(temp);
```

Comment: In your first array of `groupedItems`, the sum of the object is 99 which is below 100 is it normal or should it be 3 items in the first array ?

Comment: Yes, it is the expected, the values cannot add up to over 100

Answer (score 1):

I guess i would approch your solution like this :

Each time retrieving the first array, reducing it and if `the sum of the array + the value of your item` is less than `100`, pushing your item in the array.

Otherwise, pushing a new array in your `groupedItems` that contains your item.

There might be a better way of doing this but this is the main idea.

```js
const items = [{
    'name': 'P1',
    'value': 50
  },
  {
    'name': 'P1',
    'value': 49
  },
  {
    'name': 'P2',
    'value': 50
  },
  {
    'name': 'P3',
    'value': 50
  }
]

const groupedItems = []

items.forEach(item => {
  if (groupedItems.length > 0) {
  
  const lastArray = groupedItems[groupedItems.length - 1]

    const sumLastArray = lastArray.reduce((total, current) => current.value + total,
      0)

    if (sumLastArray + item.value < 100) {
      lastArray.push(item)
    } else {
      groupedItems.push([item])
    }
  } else {
    groupedItems.push([item])
  }



})

console.log(groupedItems)
```